# CSS : How to remove margin between <li>

Tags: css, html-lists

I created tabs using `<li>`. I used css to add style but the problem is, there is a space between tabs. I tried to add `margin: 0px;` in `ul.tabs li` but the spaces are still there.

Please see the link http://jsfiddle.net/cfv65agn/

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change margin in "ul.tabs li" to a negative number. -3 gets rid of them, -2 makes them real small.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward fix is to set the font size of your ul with the class "tabs" to 0, and set the proper font size on the list items directly.

This will remove the default spacing between them, without the need of magical negative numbers.

I just tested, and the following works:

```
 ul.tabs {

   font-size: 0;

 }

 ul.tabs li {

  font-size: 16px; /* set to the font size you want */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding float: left to your ul and li will fix it too (make ul 100% width as well):

**CSS**

```
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
ul.tabs li {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #222;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #afafaf;
    margin : 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eacq5xtz/)

Answer (score 1):

probably it is because you have set `display:inline-block` in `ul.tabs li`.
changing it to `float:left`will fix this. this usually happens when there is a `\n` between `inline-block` elements

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block` will honour white-space between them. Simply delete the tabs an spaces between your li's. The will unfortunately make your code slightly less readable, but you can more or less compensate by putting a line break within the li, at the end.